# Kotlin Button to Load RecyclerView Data - Needs Two Presses

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Firstly apologies for what i'm sure is a newby mistake somewhere. Just started learning Kotlin and likely thrown myself in the deep end, but i've got some understanding of what is happening.

**My Context:**

I'm using a button to load JSON data from a file on my server, before displaying it into a Recycler View.
The data loads fine into the recycler view list item nicely, but:

**My Problem:**

In order for the recyclerview to display the JSON data (which i'm getting with Volley), the button needs pressing *twice*.

On first press, nothing happens. Second press, the data updates.
I change the json on my server, press the button - nothing happens - recyclerview remains unchanged.
Press it again, and the recyclerview updates.

```
MainClass.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
    val serviceList: ArrayList<Service> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.parsebtn)

        val recycleradapter = Itemadapter(this, serviceList)
        val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
        recyclerview.adapter = recycleradapter
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            jsonParse()
            recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    }
    private fun jsonParse() {

        val url = "MYSERVERIP/test.json"
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                response ->try {
                    serviceList.clear()
                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("services")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val serviceRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val serviceOrigin = serviceRow.getString("origin")
                        val serviceDestination = serviceRow.getString("destination")
                        val serviceID = serviceRow.getString("train uid")
                        serviceList.add(Service(serviceOrigin, serviceDestination, serviceID))
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
        }, {
                error -> error.printStackTrace()
        })
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Adapter Class:

```
class Itemadapter (private val context: Context, private val dataset: ArrayList<Service>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Itemadapter.ItemViewHolder>()
{
    class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val txtSOrigin: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.serviceOrigin)
        val txtSDest: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.serviceDestination)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.txtSOrigin.text = item.sOrigin
        holder.txtSDest.text = item.sDest
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

And then the service dataclass:

```
data class Service(var trainid: String, var sOrigin: String, var sDest: String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REASON**: This happens because the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called as sequentially and actually then you don't have any data inside the `serviceList`, so it is more suitable to call that method after call has completed and a response has received

**SOLUTION**:

Conceptually, you should understand how asynchronous programming works.You misunderstood asynchronous programming with sequential execution and thus the above mistake

What now?

Move your `recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to the place where you receive the response from the server like so in the `Response.Listener` interface instance

```
try {
                    serviceList.clear()
                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("services")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val serviceRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val serviceOrigin = serviceRow.getString("origin")
                        val serviceDestination = serviceRow.getString("destination")
                        val serviceID = serviceRow.getString("train uid")
                        serviceList.add(Service(serviceOrigin, serviceDestination, serviceID))
                        recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // Here
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
```

Also you can show certain kind of progress mechanism like a bar or a shimmer layout when the button is pressed and hide the visibility when the data is received from the server

Answer (score 1):

Making HTTP request with Volley is asynchronous, so there is a big probability that the list of services is populated **after** notifying the adapter. So, you should refresh the RecyclerView when you actully got the result from the server:

```kotlin
response ->try {
    serviceList.clear()
    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("services")
    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
        val serviceRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
        val serviceOrigin = serviceRow.getString("origin")
        val serviceDestination = serviceRow.getString("destination")
        val serviceID = serviceRow.getString("train uid")
        serviceList.add(Service(serviceOrigin, serviceDestination, serviceID))
    }
    runOnUiThread {
        recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
} catch (e: JSONException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```